# Python Find Times Not Consecutive In List

Tags: python, pandas

I have two df's like this:

```
df1
x   y
0   64
1   57
2   51
3   46
4   
5   
6   35
7   
8   
9   29

df2
x   y
0   85
1   22
2   77
3   65
4   21
5   13
6   34
7   98
8   
9   29
```

I'm trying to find how many holes there are in each list. In df1, there are 2 holes, meaning there are two spots where there is a break in continuous numbers. In df2, there is one hole.

If I save the non-empty x values like below, I have a list of numbers.

```
df3 = df1.loc[~df1['y'].isnull()]
listcheck = df3['x'].tolist()

print(listcheck)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9]
```

Can I use this list to figure out the holes as described above?

Comment: Hi. Could you show some code you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
num_holes = 0

# find hole at beginning of array
if listcheck[0] > 0:
    num_holes += 1

# find hole at end of array
if listcheck[-1] != len(df1)-1:
    num_holes += 1

# find hole in the middle of array
for i in range(len(listcheck) - 1):
    if listcheck[i+1] - listcheck[i] > 1:
        num_holes += 1

print(num_holes)
```

Comment: Thanks I like this one. Very simple and more along the lines of my ability :)

Comment: FYI, this won't give you the right result if your dataframe is missing first or last values.

Comment: I made a fix on it

Comment: a hole needs 2 margins so the initial code was fine, ofc depends on the OP requirements

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
holes = 0
for i, j in zip(listcheck[:-1], listcheck[1:]):
    if j - i > 1:
        holes += 1
print(holes)
# output: 2
```

Comment: @maxutil check now

Comment: That works! Thank you rusu_ro1. I need to study this code later to figure out how it works.

Comment: the code is base on the observation that if 2 neighbor numbers from your listcheck are not consecutive this mean there is a hole

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best approach, but this is the first thing that comes to my mind:

```
tmp = [-1]+listcheck+len(df1)    # Add boundaries to see if first (0) and the last elements are also missing
holes = sum([1 for i in range(1, len(listcheck)+2) if tmp[i] != tmp[i-1]+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,None,3, 4, None, None, 5]})
temp = df.isna()
counter = 0
isna = False
for i in range(len(df)):
    if temp['A'].iloc[i]:
        if isna == False:
            counter += 1
            isna = True
    else:
        isna = False
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have in mind might seem a little bit confusing, but it will be quite fast on bigger dataframes:

```
number_of_consecutive_gaps = np.sum(np.diff(df['x'][df['y'].isnull()]) > 1)
number_of_initial_gaps = 1 if df['x'][df['y'].isnull()].shape[0] > 0 else 0
number_of_gaps = number_of_consecutive_gaps + number_of_initial_gaps
```

However the underlying assumption is that `df['x']` is increasing by a single unit of `1`, if that is not the case, you can just replace `df['x']` with `df.index` and make sure the index goes consecutively up and then it will still be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need mask `.isna` and `.notna` with `shift` to find the locations where values change from `non-NaN` to `NaN` and count `True` values

```
(df1.y.isna() & df1.y.notna().shift(fill_value=True)).value_counts()[True]

Out[1073]: 2
```

On df2:

```
(df2.y.isna() & df2.y.notna().shift(fill_value=True)).value_counts()[True]

Out[1076]: 1
```